# Jquery Date picker display on top

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I want the jquery date picker to appear above, i.e, partly within and outside the iframe, like the one in the image below. By the way, the iframe is just a very small part of the page.

[image: Calender appearing partly out of the iframe]

But what I am getting is this.

[image: Calender appearing within the iframe]
Can anyone please help with me a workaround and achieve a result similar to the 1st image? The date picker I am using is the one in jquery UI date picker.

Comment: Can someone please help with a solution? The solution may be simple but I am unable to think of it.

Comment: I tried the z-index too, but its not working. I want the date picker to be displayed partly inside and mostly outside the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have position relative set on your container. This could cause your absolutely positioned datepicker to hide within the container. Please try removing any position rule, or using position static.

Comment: @ ianisted Thank you for the quick reply. I tried the `position: relative` but still the date picker is hidden within the iframe. I want it to be displayed outside the iframe like my first image.

Comment: @Freakyuser why did you put the question as resolved? I'have the same pb seams there is no easy solution